# How should I address this custom menu error?

Tags: menu, google-sheets

This error occurs when using my custom menu designed to clear a range of cells from  7 sheets within the same document. The code is as follows:

```
function onOpen() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var menubuttons = [{name: "Clear Dock 1", functionName: "clearRange1()"},
                   {name: "Clear Dock 2", functionName: "clearRange2()"},
                   {name: "Clear Dock 3", functionName: "clearRange3()"},
                   {name: "Clear Dock 4", functionName: "clearRange4()"},
                   {name: "Clear Dock 5", functionName: "clearRange5()"},
                   {name: "Clear Dock 6", functionName: "clearRange6()"},
                   {name: "Clear Dock 7", functionName: "clearRange7()"}

              ];




function clearRange1() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Dock 1');
  sheet.getRange('b2:j49').clearContent();
}


function clearRange2() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Dock 2');
  sheet.getRange('b2:j49').clearContent();
}

function clearRange3() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Dock 3');
  sheet.getRange('b2:j49').clearContent();
}

function clearRange4() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Dock 4');
  sheet.getRange('b2:j49').clearContent();
}

function clearRange5() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Dock 5');
  sheet.getRange('b2:j49').clearContent();
}

function clearRange6() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Dock 6');
  sheet.getRange('b2:j49').clearContent();
}

function clearRange7() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Dock 7');
  sheet.getRange('b2:j49').clearContent();
}}
```

I am very new to coding and I am eager to learn as I am developing a shipping/receiving schedule for my workplace. My code may contain a lot of errors and thus any corrections would be awesome :).

The issue persists whenever I press the buttons on my custom menu, as it gives me the error: **"Script function not found: clearRange1() For more information, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#addItem(String,String)"**, consistently. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly I don't know how you got a custom menu unless you've omitted your code for that.

Below details how you would need to format to get a custom menu.
Secondly your functions should be separate from all the other functions. So an onOpen() function will close } , then you'll start another function which is separate.  See below for the example you can expand upon :)

```
function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Clear Dock 1', 'clearRange1')
      .addItem('Clear Dock 2', 'clearRange2')
      .addItem('Clear Dock 3', 'clearRange3')
      .addItem('Clear Dock 4', 'clearRange4')
      .addItem('Clear Dock 5', 'clearRange5')
      .addItem('Clear Dock 6', 'clearRange6')
      .addItem('Clear Dock 7', 'clearRange7')
      .addToUi();
}

    //you can put this outside your functions if you want it to work for all of them
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function clearRange1() {

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
sheet.getRange('B2:J49').clearContent();

}
```

Comment: David, Thank you so much for helping me with this. My menu is working and all is running smoothly.

Comment: Thanks @GiulianoIaboni , glad I could help.  If you could please mark the answer as correct it will be helpful to future onlookers :)